# Regex issues in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am unable to detect the issues in my perl script as below; Any help.

```
my $TotalTestRunUI = undef;
my $TotalTestPassUI = undef;
my $TotalTestFailUI = undef;
my $TotalTestSkippedUI = undef;
my $PercentageTestPassedUI = undef;

# REG EXX EXPRESSION IN FILE - 12/12/0/0

open(FILE1, "ci_report.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

print "Rajesh 1\n";

while (<FILE1>) {
    print "Rajesh 2\n";

    if($_ =~ #^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$#)
    {
        $TotalTestRunUI = $1;
        $TotalTestPassUI = $2;
        $TotalTestFailUI = $3;
        $TotalTestSkippedUI = $4;
        $PercentageTestPassedUI = ($2/$1*100);

        print $1;
        print $2;
        print $3;
        print $4;

    print "Rajesh 3\n";
    }
  close();
}

print "Rajesh 4\n";
```

Comment: what exactly is  the prob...desired output not coming or code not running at all or some error???

Comment: Why are you using `//` instead of just `/`?

Comment: Seems my regex has some problem. The content of the file is - 12/12/0/0 which will beused to create matrix.

Comment: What is `echo`? That is not a Perl function. Are you joining us from PHP, perhaps?

Comment: Thats typo but stil are r having regex issues in the script.

Comment: Bascially i have one text file which has entry is such format - 12/12/0/0 which consist of test results. I need to get value of each separted by / and use it in my script.

Comment: There are some compilcation error as below;\syntax error at test.pl line 20, near "$TotalTestPassUI "
syntax error at test.pl line 33, near "}"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $TotalTestRunUI = undef;
my $TotalTestPassUI = undef;
my $TotalTestFailUI = undef;
my $TotalTestSkippedUI = undef;
my $PercentageTestPassedUI = undef;

# REG EXX EXPRESSION IN FILE - 12/12/0/0

open(FILE1, "ci_report.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

print "Rajesh 1\n";

while (<FILE1>) {
    print "Rajesh 2\n";

    if($_ =~ /^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/)
    {
        $TotalTestRunUI = $1;
        $TotalTestPassUI = $2;
        $TotalTestFailUI = $3;
        $TotalTestSkippedUI = $4;
        $PercentageTestPassedUI = ($2/$1*100);

        print $1;
        print $2;
        print $3;
        print $4;

    print "Rajesh 3\n";
    }

}

print "Rajesh 4\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a call to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function:

```
while (<FILE1>) {
    chomp;

    print "Rajesh 2\n";
    if($_ =~ #^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$#)
```